# Use curve points to define a function

Tags: javascript, function, curve

I'm trying to compute values from 0 to 1 but not according to a mathematical equation, but rather I want to define my own points, similar to the Curves in Photoshop. And the result would be computed from that curve.

[image]

So, for example I compute f(0.5) and it returns 0.28 and so on.

Is there a way to do this in Javascript?
Thank you.

Comment: what other variables? it is `0.5-0.28 = 0.22` ?

Comment: So, you define this curve by providing the points. The interval is normalized(0 to 1), then you provide a valur for the input, say x, which is again between 0 and 1 and the function will provide the output value for that x input. In our case f(x) = f(0.5) = 0.28.